# Scala Built Tool in HP UX

Tags: scala, unix, sbt, hp-ux, sbt-plugin

I was trying to install sbt on HPUX by downloading zip file `https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html`

During Installation i encountered below error ""Caused by: lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.shaded.io.github.soc.directories.UnsupportedOperatingSystemException: directories are not supported on HP-UX"

Can anyone clarify is HP UX will not compatible with SBT ?

Comment: How did you try to install it? Do you mean compilation of the project? have you tried to remove addSbtPlugin("io.get-coursier"   % "sbt-coursier" % "1.0.0-RC13")

Comment: Can you please assist me more precisely how to remove this plugin while installing. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Which commands are you running before this error happen? are you compiling a Scala project?

Comment: Java -jar sbt-launch.jar This is the command i executed

Comment: Check in your project you will have a folder called project and inside you will have files with the sbt plugin information?

Comment: I am doing a manual installation of SBT it's not allowing to create project folder itself. Well prior to that step i am facing this error

Comment: i have files sbt, sbt.bat, java9-rt-export.jar, sbt-launch.jar